# Find the limit of trigonometric function

Tags: calculus

$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}(\frac{2}{\pi}\text{arctan}\;x)^{x}
$$

Even though I've expanded via Taylor series, I can't figure out

Comment: You say you have expanded to a Taylor series, but do not say where that series is centered or what is your series.

Comment: Hint: It is sufficient to evaluate $\lim_{x\to\infty}x\ln\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan x\right)$. Attempting to evaluate this limit directly results in the indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$. Can you manipulate the expression to apply L'Hôpital's Rule?

Comment: @A.E.Rosas I did that, but couldn't go further

Answer (score 1):

This is of the form $\left[1^\infty\right]$, which one may address by taking logarithms to obtain the more familiar $[\infty \cdot 0]$ form.

Let $L = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)^x $.  By the continuity of the logarithm, we may exchange the logarithm and the limit, then apply a familiar property of logarithms.
\begin{align*}
\ln L &= \ln \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)^x  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \ln \left( \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)^x \right)  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} x \ln \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)  \\
\end{align*}
Then, as is typical for an application of l'Hopital's rule, we continue.
\begin{align*}
\ln L &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln \left( \frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)}{1/x}  \\
    &\overset{l'H}{=} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{\pi (x^2 + 1)}}{-1/x^2}  \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-2x^2}{\pi (x^2 + 1)}
\end{align*}
We perhaps already recognize the value of the limit.  Perhaps we continue using l'Hopital's rule again.  Alternatively, this is a rational function so we can proceed by factoring out "the big part".
\begin{align*}
\ln L &= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left( \frac{x^2}{x^2} \cdot \frac{-2}{\pi(1 + x^{-2})}   \right)  \\
    &= \frac{-2}{\pi(1+0)}  \\
    &= -2/\pi  \text{.}
\end{align*}
So $L = \mathrm{e}^{-2/\pi}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you *compose* Taylor series (that is to say working one piece at the time), not only you will get the limit but also the asymptotics of the function.
$$y=\Big[\frac{2}{\pi } \tan ^{-1}(x)\Big]^x\implies \log(y)=x \log\Big[\frac{2}{\pi } \tan ^{-1}(x)\Big]$$
$$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}-\frac{1}{5
   x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)$$
$$\frac{2}{\pi } \tan ^{-1}(x)=1-\frac{2}{\pi  x}+\frac{2}{3 \pi  x^3}-\frac{2}{5 \pi 
   x^5}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^7}\right)$$
$$\log\Big[\frac{2}{\pi } \tan ^{-1}(x)\Big]=-\frac{2}{\pi  x}-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x^2}+\frac{2 \left(\pi ^2-4\right)}{3 \pi ^3
   x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$\log(y)=-\frac{2}{\pi  }-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x}+\frac{2 \left(\pi ^2-4\right)}{3 \pi ^3
   x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^{-\frac 2\pi } \left(1-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x}+\frac{2 \left(3-4 \pi +\pi ^3\right)}{3 \pi ^4
   x^2}\right)+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Make $x=123.456$; the "exact" value is $0.5282144850$ while the above expansion gives $0.5282144663$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\dfrac{2\arctan x}\pi=1+y$

$x=\tan\left(\dfrac\pi2+\dfrac{y\pi}2\right)=-\cot?$

We have $$\left(\lim_{y\to0^+}(1+y)^{1/y}\right)^{-\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac y{\cot\dfrac{y\pi}2}}$$

The inner limit converges to $e,$ right?

What about the limit in the exponent?